# Google Map Doesn't appear on the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

Google Map doesn't appear on my android device. I did everything right.  I have created certificate fingerprint from command prompt.
Then I got Map API Key from my Google console and I gave all the permission inside in the Manifest.XML including API Key put with in the activity

I checked everything right but, why map doesn't display on my device.

Android Manifest.XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.justsee.androidapi" >
    <permission
        android:name="com.justsee.androidapi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.justsee.androidapi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIza**************************" />

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

```
  Main_activity.java


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private GoogleMap map;
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder;
    CameraUpdate cu;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        /**call the map set up method*/
        mSetUpMap();



    }

    public void mSetUpMap() {
        /**clear the map before redraw to them*/
        map.clear();
        /**Create dummy Markers List*/
        List<Marker> markersList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
        Marker Delhi = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                28.61, 77.2099)).title("Delhi"));
        Marker Chaandigarh = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                30.75, 76.78)).title("Chandigarh"));
        Marker SriLanka = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                7.000, 81.0000)).title("Sri Lanka"));
        Marker America = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                38.8833, 77.0167)).title("America"));
        Marker Arab = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                24.000, 45.000)).title("Arab"));

        /**Put all the markers into arraylist*/
        markersList.add(Delhi);
        markersList.add(SriLanka);
        markersList.add(America);
        markersList.add(Arab);
        markersList.add(Chaandigarh);

        /**create for loop for get the latLngbuilder from the marker list*/
        builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (Marker m : markersList) {
            builder.include(m.getPosition());
        }
        /**initialize the padding for map boundary*/
        int padding = 50;
        /**create the bounds from latlngBuilder to set into map camera*/
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        /**create the camera with bounds and padding to set into map*/
        cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
        /**call the map call back to know map is loaded or not*/
        map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
                /**set animated zoom camera into map*/
                map.animateCamera(cu);

            }
        });
    }



}






Logcat:


  04-20 12:51:18.761  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi W/Typeface﹕ getVibeFontPathWithCTS(): fontPath =
04-20 12:51:18.761  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi W/Typeface﹕ getVibeFontPathWithCTS(): fontName =
04-20 12:51:18.761  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi W/Typeface﹕ getVibeFontPathWithCTS(): isForceToSystemDefault = false
04-20 12:51:18.761  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi W/Typeface﹕ VIBEUI_setThemeFont(): sVibeFontPath =  ,fontPath =
04-20 12:51:18.761  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi W/Typeface﹕ VIBEUI_setThemeFont(): FontPath Not Changed!
04-20 12:51:18.765  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/wangcy9﹕ setStatusIcon occur wrong theme!
04-20 12:51:18.747  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi V/ActivityThread﹕ Handling launch of ActivityRecord{50ef897 token=android.os.BinderProxy@12e80a84 {com.justsee.googlemapapi/com.justsee.googlemapapi.MainActivity}}
04-20 12:51:18.747  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi V/ActivityThread﹕ ActivityRecord{50ef897 token=android.os.BinderProxy@12e80a84 {com.justsee.googlemapapi/com.justsee.googlemapapi.MainActivity}}: app=android.app.Application@3fd837c3, appName=com.justsee.googlemapapi, pkg=com.justsee.googlemapapi, comp={com.justsee.googlemapapi/com.justsee.googlemapapi.MainActivity}, dir=/data/app/com.justsee.googlemapapi-1/base.apk
04-20 12:51:18.778  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 8703248
04-20 12:51:18.801  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/AbsListView﹕ checkAbsListViewlLogProperty get invalid command
04-20 12:51:18.823  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi V/ActivityThread﹕ Performing resume of ActivityRecord{50ef897 token=android.os.BinderProxy@12e80a84 {com.justsee.googlemapapi/com.justsee.googlemapapi.MainActivity}}
04-20 12:51:18.823  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{50ef897 token=android.os.BinderProxy@12e80a84 {com.justsee.googlemapapi/com.justsee.googlemapapi.MainActivity}}
04-20 12:51:18.823  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi V/ActivityThread﹕ Resume ActivityRecord{50ef897 token=android.os.BinderProxy@12e80a84 {com.justsee.googlemapapi/com.justsee.googlemapapi.MainActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
04-20 12:51:18.823  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi V/PhoneWindow﹕ DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2618e26d I.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
04-20 12:51:18.825  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/ViewRootImpl﹕ hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{8750514 com.justsee.googlemapapi/com.justsee.googlemapapi.MainActivity,ident = 1}
04-20 12:51:18.832  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi V/ActivityThread﹕ Resuming ActivityRecord{50ef897 token=android.os.BinderProxy@12e80a84 {com.justsee.googlemapapi/com.justsee.googlemapapi.MainActivity}} with isForward=true
04-20 12:51:18.832  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi V/PhoneWindow﹕ DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{8750514 com.justsee.googlemapapi/com.justsee.googlemapapi.MainActivity,ident = 1}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2618e26d V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
04-20 12:51:18.832  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi V/ActivityThread﹕ Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{50ef897 token=android.os.BinderProxy@12e80a84 {com.justsee.googlemapapi/com.justsee.googlemapapi.MainActivity}}
04-20 12:51:18.833  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/ActivityThread﹕ ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{50ef897 token=android.os.BinderProxy@12e80a84 {com.justsee.googlemapapi/com.justsee.googlemapapi.MainActivity}}
04-20 12:51:18.852  11173-11226/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ CanvasContext() 0x5587386310 initialize 0x55874ed5f0
04-20 12:51:18.852  11173-11226/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/Surface﹕ Surface::connect(this=0x55874ed5e0,api=1)
04-20 12:51:18.853  11173-11226/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000
04-20 12:51:18.853  11173-11226/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/Surface﹕ Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x55874ed5e0)
04-20 12:51:18.853  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/AbsListView﹕ onWindowFocusChanged: hasWindowFocus=true, this=maps.ei.k{204b4e4c G.ED..C. ......I. 0,0-0,0}
04-20 12:51:18.853  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi V/InputMethodManager﹕ onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#81810100
04-20 12:51:18.853  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi V/InputMethodManager﹕ START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2618e26d V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-1080,1920} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@2a275e80 controlFlags=#104
04-20 12:51:18.860  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi I/BufferQueue﹕ [unnamed-11173-1](this:0x55875059c0,id:1,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) BufferQueue core=(11173:com.justsee.googlemapapi)
04-20 12:51:18.861  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi I/BufferQueueConsumer﹕ [unnamed-11173-1](this:0x55875059c0,id:1,api:0,p:-1,c:11173) connect(C): consumer=(11173:com.justsee.googlemapapi) controlledByApp=true
04-20 12:51:18.861  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi I/BufferQueueConsumer﹕ [unnamed-11173-1](this:0x55875059c0,id:1,api:0,p:-1,c:11173) setConsumerName: unnamed-11173-1
04-20 12:51:18.861  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi I/BufferQueueConsumer﹕ [unnamed-11173-1](this:0x55875059c0,id:1,api:0,p:-1,c:11173) setDefaultBufferSize: width=1080 height=1845
04-20 12:51:18.863  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/MALI﹕ eglCreateContext:206: [MALI] eglCreateContext display 0x5587179060, share context 0x0 here.
04-20 12:51:18.864  11173-11226/com.justsee.googlemapapi I/GLConsumer﹕ [unnamed-11173-1] attachToContext
04-20 12:51:18.866  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/MALI﹕ gles_context_new:248: Create GLES ctx 0x7f695b7018 successfully
04-20 12:51:18.866  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/MALI﹕ eglCreateContext:543: [MALI] eglCreateContext end. Created context 0x558738baa0 here.
04-20 12:51:18.866  11173-11226/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/Surface﹕ Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x55874ed5e0,w=1080,h=1920)
04-20 12:51:18.866  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/Surface﹕ Surface::connect(this=0x5587411ee0,api=1)
04-20 12:51:18.867  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi I/BufferQueueProducer﹕ [unnamed-11173-1](this:0x55875059c0,id:1,api:1,p:11173,c:11173) connect(P): api=1 producer=(11173:com.justsee.googlemapapi) producerControlledByApp=true
04-20 12:51:18.867  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000
04-20 12:51:18.868  11173-11226/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/GraphicBuffer﹕ register, handle(0x558751fa90) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
04-20 12:51:18.942  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/Surface﹕ Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x5587411ee0,w=1080,h=1845)
04-20 12:51:18.942  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi I/BufferQueueProducer﹕ [unnamed-11173-1](this:0x55875059c0,id:1,api:1,p:11173,c:11173) new GraphicBuffer needed
04-20 12:51:18.945  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/GraphicBuffer﹕ register, handle(0x55874e4fb0) (w:1080 h:1845 s:1088 f:0x2 u:0x000300)
04-20 12:51:18.955  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/Surface﹕ Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x5587411ee0,w=1080,h=1845)
04-20 12:51:18.955  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi I/BufferQueueProducer﹕ [unnamed-11173-1](this:0x55875059c0,id:1,api:1,p:11173,c:11173) new GraphicBuffer needed
04-20 12:51:18.959  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/GraphicBuffer﹕ register, handle(0x55874e8ac0) (w:1080 h:1845 s:1088 f:0x2 u:0x000300)
04-20 12:51:18.962  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi I/BufferQueueProducer﹕ [unnamed-11173-1](this:0x55875059c0,id:1,api:1,p:11173,c:11173) queueBuffer: slot 0 is dropped, handle=0x55874e4fb0
04-20 12:51:19.242  11173-11226/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/Surface﹕ Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x55874ed5e0,w=1080,h=1920)
04-20 12:51:19.246  11173-11226/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/GraphicBuffer﹕ register, handle(0x5587481100) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
04-20 12:51:25.704  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/ViewRootImpl﹕ doProcessInputEvents ViewRoot{8750514 com.justsee.googlemapapi/com.justsee.googlemapapi.MainActivity,ident = 1}
04-20 12:51:25.704  11173-11173/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/View﹕ Touch up dispatch to maps.dg.p{4448e77 VFED..C. ........ 0,0-1080,1845}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=621.4246, y[0]=815.53613, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=103374561, downTime=103374481, deviceId=10, source=0x1002 }
04-20 12:51:25.930  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/Surface﹕ Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x5587411ee0,w=1080,h=1845)
04-20 12:51:25.934  11173-12151/com.justsee.googlemapapi I/BufferQueueProducer﹕ [unnamed-11173-1](this:0x55875059c0,id:1,api:1,p:11173,c:11173) queueBuffer: fps=0.29 dur=6983.02 max=6971.79 min=11.24
04-20 12:51:25.940  11173-11226/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/Surface﹕ Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x55874ed5e0,w=1080,h=1920)
04-20 12:51:25.942  11173-11226/com.justsee.googlemapapi D/GraphicBuffer﹕ register, handle(0x55874854b0) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
```

Comment: You should post relevant code with stack trace if any.

Comment: where is your code and xml ??

Comment: if everything is right than it should display map.may be something wrong. please show your code.

Comment: Provide Android monitor log too

Comment: I sent everything there please let you check that

Comment: A blank map is ALWAYS an api key issue.  Check your logs for details about exactly what the problem is.  Also make sure that you enabled Google Maps Android API in the developer console.

Comment: I enabled Google Map Android API in the developer console but doesn't show

Comment: i have created sha1 finger print certificate below i mentioned here.                                 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\admin\
.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass andro
id

Comment: Sry,i wasn't enable the developer console but now i enabled developer google console it's work .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the OnMapReadyCallback interface and use the onMapReady(GoogleMap) callback method to get a handle to the GoogleMap object. And then, call getMapAsync() on the fragment to register the callback. Refer to the code below.

```
public class GoogleMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback    {

    private GoogleMap gMap;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}
```

And in your OnMapReady callback.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    gMap = googleMap;
    // additional code here

}
```

hope this will somehow help you

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#add_a_map_to_an_android_app

Comment: I used even onMapReadyCallback it doesn't show and i used default MapsActivity.My map doesn't show on my device

Comment: There is no error i didn't  enabled the Google developer console that's map doesn't appear now i enabled working like a charm thanka lot